# Excel VBA Run-Time Error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' Failed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access database that is used to track daily statistics for a group.  I have created a button that will export the results of a query to a .xlsx and then create and format a pivot table for review by the groups management.

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qry_daily_report", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "Z:\Users\jondoe\..........\Desktop\Export\qry_daily_report.xlsx", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint



Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("Z:\Users\jondoe\..........\Desktop\Export\qry_daily_report.xlsx")
appExcel.Visible = True


ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$H$50000"), , xlYes).Name = "qry_daily_report"
```

The FIRST time i click the button the export and pivot table creation works perfectly as intended.  However, when I close the .xlsx and then click the button again, the export will work but the code to create the pivot table will not execute.  Instead I get an error..."Excel VBA Run-Time Error '1004' Method 'Range' of object'_Global' Failed".  When I try to debug it, I following is highlighted as the error.

```
 ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$H$50000"), , xlYes).Name = "qry_daily_report"
```

I find that if I close the database and reopen it, again, the export and pivot table works perfectly.  Likewise, If I save the database and the click the button, the export and pivot table work perfectly.   Neither option is reasonable for my client.

Anybody have an idea on how I can remedy this error, please?

Comment: Do you want to save the workbook? Do you want to save to same workbook name every time?

Comment: Do you unbind the instance of Excel in your code? I've seen nothing like `Set appExcel = Nothing`. Also, your code is mixing late binding and early binding. Check https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/early-late-binding/#:~:text=It's%20easy%20to%20tell%20the,be%20desirable%20In%20some%20instances.

Comment: You already have your answer given by Erik. A small suggestion that I would like to give is.. avoid the use of `Activesheet`. If your workbook has more than 1 worksheet then you may get unexpected results because the active sheet may not be the sheet you think is active. Always work with objects. For example `Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet` and then something like `Set ws = myWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` and finally `ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range("$A$1:$H$50000"), , xlYes).Name = "qry_daily_report"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range("$A$1:$H$50000")` is called from global, not from the Excel application.

Same goes for `ActiveSheet`.

Always be explicit about *which* Excel instance you're using if you're not using Excel itself.

```
appExcel.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, appExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$50000"), , xlYes).Name = "qry_daily_report"
```